# Server failing to start after deploying web api to azure using visual studio

Tags: asp.net, azure, deployment

I am trying to deploy a web api to azure using visual studio and i am getting a "HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start" error. The project is using an sql database and everything works fine locally. The problem arises when i deploy and try and use the azure sql database.I saw a video on youtube that said the problem could be because of the lack of a connection string in azure and that i should add it in the web app configuration settings. But the problem is i cant find this option in Azure. I am aslo wondering why that would be an issue because when i publish the app in visual studio, i create a database and the option of saving the connection string is already auto selected and I didn't change it.

Failed to start error:

[image]

I tried to deploy my web Api to a windows web app but the server is failing to start

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a sample ASP. NET Core 6 API with SQL Server and deployed it to the Azure App Service successfully.

I added the following code to my Program.cs class.

**Program.cs**

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<studentDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("studentconn")));

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
{
    x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        x.RoutePrefix = "swagger"; // For localhost
    else
        x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    //  For azure
}
);
```

The Azure SQL connection string is provided below and has been added to the appsettings.json file.

**appsettings.json**:

```json
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "studentconn": "Server=tcp:<ServerName>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<DataBaseName>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<UserName>;Password=<Password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  }
```

**.csproj**:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.26" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="6.0.26" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.26" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.26">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I added the client IP address to the Azure SQL Server, as shown below:

[image]

It ran locally successfully with Azure SQL Server.

**Local Output**:

[image]

I successfully published a web API through Visual Studio, as shown below:

[image]

**Azure Web App Output** :

[image]